# Global Variables on Quartz Composer

Tags: javascript, quartz-composer

I am wondering how to create a Javascript Patch with global variables.

Then, access them from any other patch.

Here is an example of how I would use that.

**Javascript Patch #1**

```
var debugMode = true
```

**Javascript Patch #2**

```
retrives debugMode from memory and outputs true or false
```

**Javascript Patch #2 connected to SpritePatch via Enable**

```
if debugMode is true enable.
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I think it would be useful anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deep search I have found that Kineme has a plugin that allows what I am trying to achieve.

[Data Tools](http://kineme.net/release/DataTools/12)

> (If you are using Mac Os 10.9 you should [read this](http://kineme.net/forum/General/KinemeDataToolsin109))